# Is it possivel have an asynchronous Google Overlays service to draw a real time route?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, asynchronous

I'm using google overlays to draw my walking route in real time, I have a web service obtaining my gps coordinate and trying to draw in realtime the line. At the moment i'm refreshing every 10 seconds...

I would like to know if it is possible to asynchronous refresh the map everytime i obtain a new position ?

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check out https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions.

Path:

> The ordered sequence of coordinates of the Polyline. This path may be
>   specified using either a simple array of LatLngs, or an MVCArray of
>   LatLngs. Note that if you pass a simple array, it will be converted to
>   an MVCArray Inserting or removing LatLngs in the MVCArray will
>   automatically update the polyline on the map.

Comment: thanks for the answer but does not solve the problem of non asynchronous communication...

Comment: Your question mentions getting data asynchronously.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you've got your project set up. Are you logging data from your phone to a web service to record it?

Comment: Yes my android phone is sending GPS information to a service provider (SP). Let's say mu wife is logged on the SP and is observing where i'm walking and what route i am doing right now. At this moment i made a js to request data from SP every 10 sec but this sounds unnecessary... i am trying to archive an asynchronous between the user and the SP in order words, the users browser only refresh when SP send a new data. ( it's like the facebook notification)

Comment: Sounds like you will need some kind of push notification service which seems a little like overkill. I don't see what was wrong with your ajax solution.